# Adding Lightning component to Outlook integration page

Tags: integration, lightning-for-outlook

I've added a custom Lightning component to my Outlook integration pane but it never shows up, neither in the preview window nor in the actual pane after saving and reloading Outlook.  Is there anything I'm missing here, does the LEX component have to be tagged somehow to show up in the Lightning pane?

The settings for the component are like this:

```
flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,force:LightningQuickAction
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`clients:availableForMailAppAppPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/clients:availableForMailAppAppPage/documentation) interface to your component and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks for that but that didn't do the trick.  There's definitely something I'm missing in the documentation.

Comment: Did you also try adding `clients:hasItemContext` as well?  I've implemented an aura component within the Gmail email pane and it worked for me.  Maybe it's an outlook specific issue

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of your component can also depend on what your component does and whether it is functioning as planned. For example, if you build a replacement people component that displays people as individual cards, it will be invisible in the app builder and in Outlook if there is no data to display. If your component is visible in app builder and not in Outlook, then suggest you check for filters on your component in app builder and visibility of your custom panel by profile in the Outlook integration settings.